# How do I convert a 12 hour format date/time string into 24 hours?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've tried searching everywhere to find a solution for this but nothing I'm trying is working.

I have a date/time string in a 12 hour UK format:

```
20-07-2017 04:45 PM
```

I'm trying to convert that into the following 24 hour clock:

```
Y-m-d H:i:00
```

And here's the PHP I was trying to get to work...

```
$start_date = $_POST['startdate'];
$newstartdate = new DateTime($start_date);
$start_date = $newstartdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:00') ;
```

Am I misusing this? Should I be taking a completely diferent approach?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use code that works - or doesn't it?

Comment: how is this not working?

Comment: Try using `date_parse_from_format` so you can specify the format of the input date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the createFromFormat method on the DateTime object: [php DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

For example:

```
$newstartdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i A' ,$start_date);

$start_date = $newstartdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') ;
```

Comment: "d-m-Y H:i A" was the right format, don't know why you changed that.

Comment: Yes @NaN that's it! That's the one I was missing. I've never heard of that, but I had a feeling I needed to tell it what the format the original date/time was in, otherwise how will it know which one is the month and which one is the day. Great, thanks! -- I was about to say you needed to add 'A' but you got there first :)

Comment: @JungleZombie ah I couldnt test and wasn't overly sure the AM/PM would work, as you said it does I have now changed it back!

Comment: @Metzed Glad it is sorted